# Simulation in Proteus

Tags: power-supply, transformer, power-electronics, flyback, proteus

I want to simulate a flyback transformer in Proteus. But in the Proteus library a transformer with opposite dot convention is not available. So, how to get a transformer of opposite dot convention in Proteus simulator?

Comment: I think the default "X-Mirror" shortcut is CTRL+M or you can right-click on the component and choose the rotation you want.

Comment: Just reverse the connections to the winding you want to swap the dots on.